# how to record video of my ongoing screen on kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, video-capture, android-4.4-kitkat, screen-capture

I want to know that how can i record video of my ongoing screen in android using Kitkat 4.4. With lot's of search on Google and SO i did not get anything.

I already saw so many link which tell's to record video by connecting device with system using USB and then writing some command in command window, but i want to record video using device only simple like when user's press record button it starts recording and when it press stop button it should stop recording.

I saw some same kind of apps on Google play like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slimdroid.screenrecoder
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.akexorcist.screenrecorder

So basically i just want some guidance that how can i achieve this, if any one have any code example then that will be great help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want is not possible except on rooted devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare, It's okay if i have to root my device, but on rooted device also how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the command prompt and locate to your sdk folder. Then fire following command

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

This will create a video file name demo.mp4 in your sd-card, and it will record whatever you do after firing above command.

To stop the recording just press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Comment: This is precisely what the OP does *not* want. The OP wants to record the screen from within an app, not from the command line.

Comment: Exactly, i already mentioned in my question itself that i do not want to use any other tool or ADB and etc... etc... I just want to record via programming.

Comment: @user3660803 then I guess you need to make you own customized code.