# Cannot record screen on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, terminal, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to record my device screen using the shell command as outlined here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord

Using the verbose flag, I am getting a Permission Denial that I think is connected to the fact there is an Owner profile on the device, as it references User 0 and User 1 in the error message.

Does anyone know how I can remove the Owner profile (can't see any options to do so) or how I can set the Owner to user 0?

EDIT - clarification, the error states "broadcast asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0"

Comment: You may try with out verbose, [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23807581/3330969).

Comment: I don't see how not using verbose will fix the error? Verbose just gives you information on the process? EDIT - just tried for the heck of it, and as I suspected, it did not help.

Comment: Sign in on the device with the owner profile before attempting the screen recording, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the recording to work.

It seems that for whatever reason, you need to do this via adb shell.

Whilst adb shell is running shell commands on the connected device, running the screenrecord commands directly on the device just doesn't want to work.